# Display array in table with 2 columns

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, tabular

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 1,
            [Value] => Value 1
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 2,
            [Value] => Value 2
        ),

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 3,
            [Value] => Value 3
        ),

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 4,
            [Value] => Value 4
        )

);
```

And I would like to create a table like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Title 1        |     Title 2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Value 1        |     Value 2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Title 3        |     Title 4      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Value 3        |     Value 4      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I have found some foreach functions, but these all give me the title with the value next to it.. Any way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Column 1, row 2: is "Value 2" correct? Should it be "Value 1", right?

Comment: you can nest another table in a cell where you render title in upper row and the value in next row.

Comment: Split items in chunks of size 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the [***modulo operator***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), which calculates the remainder of the division of two numbers. ***Modulo operations*** are often used as solutions for processes which require repetitions with iteration steps bigger than 1 and in situations were chunking big data bundles is needed. Example: when you want to send 100 emails at once, then you loop through them and send them in packages of max. 10 per iteration step.

The principle applied in your case is: Loop through the source array and output a result (two table rows) each second iteration step, beginning with the first array key.

### Version 1 - Output directly in HTML:

```
<?php
/*
 * Original array.
 */
$source = [
    0 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 1',
        'Value' => 'Value 1'
    ],
    1 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 2',
        'Value' => 'Value 2'
    ],
    2 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 3',
        'Value' => 'Value 3'
    ],
    3 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 4',
        'Value' => 'Value 4'
    ],
    4 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 5',
        'Value' => 'Value 5'
    ],
];

echo 'ORIGINAL:<pre>' . print_r($source, true) . '</pre>';

/*
 * Filter array for empty/null values.
 * The result is another array.
 */
$source = array_filter($source, function($el) {
    return !(
            empty($el['Title']) ||
            !isset($el['Title']) ||
            empty($el['Value']) ||
            !isset($el['Value'])
            );
});

echo 'FILTERED:<pre>' . print_r($source, true) . '</pre>';

/*
 * Reset array keys by applying array_values().
 * The result is another array.
 */
$source = array_values($source);

echo 'ARRAY_VALUES:<pre>' . print_r($source, true) . '</pre>';
?>

<table>
    <?php
    foreach ($source as $key => $item) {
        if ($key % 2 == 0) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($source[$key]['Title'])) {
                        echo $source[$key]['Title'];
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($source[$key + 1]['Title'])) {
                        echo $source[$key + 1]['Title'];
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($source[$key]['Value'])) {
                        echo $source[$key]['Value'];
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($source[$key + 1]['Value'])) {
                        echo $source[$key + 1]['Value'];
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

### Version 2 - Output from PHP:

```
<?php

/*
 * Original array.
 */
$source = [
    0 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 1',
        'Value' => 'Value 1'
    ],
    1 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 2',
        'Value' => 'Value 2'
    ],
    2 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 3',
        'Value' => 'Value 3'
    ],
    3 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 4',
        'Value' => 'Value 4'
    ],
    4 => [
        'Title' => 'Title 5',
        'Value' => 'Value 5'
    ],
];

echo 'ORIGINAL:<pre>' . print_r($source, true) . '</pre>';

/*
 * Filter array for empty/null values.
 * The result is another array.
 */
$source = array_filter($source, function($el) {
    return !(
            empty($el['Title']) ||
            !isset($el['Title']) ||
            empty($el['Value']) ||
            !isset($el['Value'])
            );
});

echo 'FILTERED:<pre>' . print_r($source, true) . '</pre>';

/*
 * Reset array keys by applying array_values().
 * The result is another array.
 */
$source = array_values($source);

echo 'ARRAY_VALUES:<pre>' . print_r($source, true) . '</pre>';

$tableRows = '';
foreach ($source as $key => $item) {
    if ($key % 2 == 0) {
        $tableRows .= sprintf('
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    %s
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    %s
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    %s
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    %s
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            '
                , isset($source[$key]['Title']) ? $source[$key]['Title'] : ''
                , isset($source[$key + 1]['Title']) ? $source[$key + 1]['Title'] : ''
                , isset($source[$key]['Value']) ? $source[$key]['Value'] : ''
                , isset($source[$key + 1]['Value']) ? $source[$key + 1]['Value'] : ''
        );
    }
}

echo sprintf('<table>%s</table>', $tableRows);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help on this one, precisely what i needed (Y)

Comment: @RobbTe Well, I'm glad it worked. You are welcome. Tell me please, what does it mean "(Y)"? :-)

Comment: Ah sorry, i meant; thumbs up:)

Comment: @RobbTe Why "sorry"? Au contraire, my friend: write (Y) as many as possible ;-)))

Comment: One more question. It works, but when i want to filter out an array where the Value is empty, like: `$filtered = array_filter($final, function($el) { return !empty($el['Value']); });` the code is not working anymore.. i guess because of the +1 logic... is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Give me some mins

Comment: I edited response with tests. It worked by me, BUT: I don't know where and why you use filter out function. You should use filtering function before doing any output (like table) with your array. More of this: I don't know what doesn't work to you. If you still want to use the principle of +2 iteration steps and also display table, but don't want to display a row where a value is empty/null, then you just dont echo that row based on this condition. BUT: don't make so, that the iteration steps, that symetrie is somehow preserved. Please tell me more, exactly. But in one hour, please.

Comment: Hi, your filtering works. However the foreach function does not display all the keys wilt values from the array. I guess it is because of the +1 logic, and because the arrays go from [1] to [3], without [2]. I hope you understand what i mean. If possible we can go into chat.. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148351/discussion-between-aendeerei-and-robbte).

Comment: @RobbTe We can speak in chat now. Follow the upper link. I'm there already.

Comment: @RobbTe Done updating with php version also. All final now. Bye.

Answer (score -1):

If your array is `$array`, you can use `foreach` as such:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach ($array as $row)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Value'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

`foreach` basically loops through each element in `$array` and assigns it to `$row`. Since the elements of your array are other arrays, `$row` will be an array with the information you need for each row.